# MySQL: Many tables with the FK to one table - yes or no?

Tags: mysql

I'm about to extend my DB schema (in MySQL) of the another 50+ tables. About 15-20 of them will be referencing to the table `File` (wchich stores data of the created or uploaded files in my project) The question is, what proceeding should I use:

- leave that scenario as-is
- create for each table its own `File` table

I'm asking because, if I choose the 1st option, at some point that one `File` will have the big amount of rows which it will make the CRUD operations (with the `where` clausule) slow (I suppose). So, what do You think, what would be the best idea ?

Comment: Do the easiest thing. That sounds like it means having 15 FKs referencing one column...

Comment: Yes, but that FK is only a 'connector' to the foreign table. I'll need the data from that table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep one central `File` table which is referenced by all others, unless there are to be significantly different attributes for different types of rows stored in `File`. In other words, if you are storing different sets of file metadata in the `File` table for different association types, you could find it necessary to have different file storage tables for different metadata types.

But, if you are storing the same set of file binary data, filename, MIME type, etc, commonly for all associated types, it belongs in one table.

If the table is expected to grow very large, consider [partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html) its storage.  With proper indexing, CRUD operations can be performant over millions of rows.